# trying to figure out how to use xmlhttprequest

Tags: xml, http, xmlhttprequest

I've been reading some tutorials on using xmlhttprequest, and I'm trying to piece together what I need to know to accomplish what I need to accomplish.  I'm not a web developer, and have no aspirations of being one.  I'm simply trying to control a web relay from an user created webpage with user created buttons.  at the end of the day, I need to either send a .txt file to a 192.x.x.x address on my network, or send the raw string inside of the txt document via xml to the 192.x.x.x address.

The .txt file is ridiculously small.  It's a BASIC code.  The .txt or code is the following:

LET io.relay1 = 2
END

The tutorial I'm looking at is using the following xmlhttprequest example and I'm trying to piece together how to use it for my application:

xhttp.open("POST", "script.txt", true);
xhttp.send();

I guess what I don't understand, is where am I able to specify the IP address to send the script.txt to?

Answer (score 0):

> I guess what I don't understand, is where am I able to specify the IP address to send the script.txt to?

Use an absolute URL instead of a relative one.

```
http://192.x.x.x/script.txt
```